# Slow Wireless Wifi Ubuntu 18.04, Ethernet Working Fine

Tags: wireless, 18.04, intel-wireless

On a system76 laptop, running Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS

Wireless has been working fine for a while, but now has slowed to a halt.

Network is fine and working for my iPhone.  Am currently using USB (Ethernet) hotspot to try to research and post this question.

Have tried what I know without help:

- `sudo service network-manager restart`
- restarting laptop
- restarting router and wifi

I don't really know what to do at this point, so any and all help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Other Info**

Here's some additional info from system commands that seemed useful for debugging these sorts of issues.  Please let me know if any other info is useful.

*Output from* `sudo lshw -C network`

````
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
   logical name: enp2s0f1
   version: 12
   serial: 80:fa:5b:53:54:5e
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df214000-df214fff memory:df210000-df213fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 78
   serial: 74:e5:f9:44:be:1b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-36-generic firmware=34.0.1 ip=192.168.1.202 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:135 memory:df100000-df101fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@1:11
   logical name: eth0
   serial: 42:4d:7f:ee:ba:40
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth ip=172.20.10.4 link=yes multicast=yes```
````

*Output from* `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`

```
[    3.690319] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.695795] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 34.0.1 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.724214] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    3.780293] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: 74:e5:f9:44:be:1b
[    3.858610] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

After realizing my wireless worked on other networks, but not my home wifi, I performed the [30-30-30 factory reset](https://www.lifewire.com/hard-reset-rule-for-routers-3971318) on my wifi router, and everything worked again (both before and after reconfiguring the name/password).